# What is the minimum current for my load to see TTL?

Tags: digital-logic, inverter

I have an [inverter](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/texas-instruments/SN74HCT04N/277251?utm_adgroup=Integrated%20Circuits&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Dynamic%20Search_RLSA_Cart&utm_term=&utm_content=Integrated%20Circuits&gclid=Cj0KCQiA3smABhCjARIsAKtrg6JYBvKFBOS5zs7biQCzzTV288O9YSb17RUQO8FpvHzFFQg-gL__YNIaAlUjEALw_wcB) that can output +/- 25 mA.

I would like to split that output 3 or more ways, and deliver it to as many loads.

So my **question** is: how many times can I split it before the current is too low to reach a TTL level (5, 3.3 or 2 V)?

My loads' input impedance is 8.2 MΩ. So, naïvely, I would say that the minimum current for TTL to be "seen" is I = V/R = 5 V / 8.2 MΩ = 0.6 µA. Is this reasoning too simple? Is it wrong?

Comment: What is the real load device?

Comment: It's the interlock input on a current driver.

Comment: What is the p/n?

Comment: It's home made, that's why I measured the input impedance but don't have anything else about it. Would have to chase the systems engineer who designed it years ago.

Comment: then for real info show a photo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hct04.pdf) says, (2nd bullet point) that this device can drive up to 10 LS TTL inputs. The number of inputs you can drive will depend upon family, i.e. straight TTL, LS TTL, HCT, etc.

> My loads' input impedance is 8.2 MΩ. So, naïvely, I would say that the minimum current for TTL to be "seen" is I = V/R = 5 V / 8.2 MΩ = 0.6 µA. Is this reasoning too simple?

Yes, your reasoning is too simple. A (standard) TTL input does not act like a simple resistance. It actually *supplies* current, when the input is low. The circuit driving it is expected to be able to sink that current when it is low.

Comment: Is there any way to know which family my load belongs to, without a data sheet?

Comment: If your load is an IC that begins with 74, then if the 74 is followed by a number, it is standard TTL, if followed by LS, it is "LS" family, if followed by HCT, it is "HTC" family, etc. If it is not an IC that begins with 74, then it is best to look at the datasheet.